# Button in fragment called in adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

i'm a newie android developer, i have a list with two checkbox and a button. The button is in the list class and the checkboxes are in the adapter class. When all the checkboxes are checked i have to do a fragment transaction, and here is when the button comes. There is a way to call the button from fragment in the adapter? 
I'll appreciate if anyone can tell me

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ijueces_list_rondas, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.olblTable = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTable);
            holder.olblWhite = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblWhite);
            holder.olblBlack = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblBlack);
            holder.ocheckBox1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ocheckBox2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            final CheckBox ocheckBox1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final CheckBox ocheckBox2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

            holder.ocheckBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    if(isChecked){
                        counter=0;
                        if(ocheckBox2.isChecked()==true){
                            counter=0;
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        counter--;
                    }   
                }
            });

            holder.ocheckBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    if(isChecked){
                        counter++;
                        if(ocheckBox1.isChecked()==true){

                        }
                    }
                    else{

                    }   
                }
            });
```

Sorry for the edition, i'm on a small device and it don't let me edit the code (that was my adapter class)

Comment: put your code please

Comment: what you want to do on button click?

Comment: actually i didn't understand why you need it to call from adapter? you can call it from activity.

Comment: do you want to call it automatically (without user interaction) ?

Comment: Well, after all rows of the list its checked, the button call the webservice to update de database, so the user have to click the button

Comment: The adapter contains the checkboxes, so i thought there's were i have to call the button, if it don't,  how do i call the checkboxes (to check all is checked before the button call the webservice, like a condition)  in the list class?

Comment: ok..create a method in your adapter class that return the count of checked items. and call it from your activity like `int count = adapter.getCheckedCount()` if they are all checked (count is equal to your list size ) than proceed it to web service call.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32654865/3790052] here i did same thing.. you can get some idea.

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much! Is more simple than i imagined, but without your help i couldn't know, thanks :D

Comment: your welcome...than please accept it as answer, m posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method in your adapter class that return the count of checked items. and call it from your activity like

```
int count = adapter.getCheckedCount();
```

if they are all checked (count is equal to your list size ) than proceed it to web service call.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654865/3790052) i did same thing.. you can get some idea.